# Why 999999999999999999/500000000000000000 is 2.0 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python3 and when write

print(999999999999999999/500000000000000000) it is giving me output 2.0

[image]

Comment: python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Sounds close enough to me...